# Invalid void parameter when combining template parameters to form a function signature

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Trying to take the signatures of two callbacks and generate a callback signature that uses each of their return values.

Given Callbacks `A` and `B` => Generate `F`

Ex 1) A: `int(char)` B: `double(bool)` => F: double(int)

Ex 2) A: `void(char)` B: `void(int)` => F: void(void)

Ran into a strange compiler error when instantiating a callback with `void` as a parameter:

`error: invalid parameter type ‘void’`

## Problematic Code

```
template<class Signature>
struct my_func;

template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct my_func<Ret(Args...)>
{};

template<class FuncA, class FuncB>
struct my_fwd;

template<class ORet, class... OArgs,
         class Ret, class... Args>
struct my_fwd<
  my_func<ORet(OArgs...)>,
  my_func<Ret(Args...)>
  >
{
  my_func< ORet(Ret) > func;  // <--- error
};

int main(int, char *[])
{
  my_func<void(int)> my3;  // (1)
  my_func<void(void)> my4; // (2)
  my_func<void()> my5;     // (3)

  my_fwd< decltype(my3), my_func<void(char)> > fwd1; // (4)
  my_fwd< decltype(my3), decltype(my4) > fwd2;       // (5)

  return 0;
}
```

Though there are no problems with the instantiation of `my_func`'s with `void` `(1), (2), (3)`, the `my_fwd`'s `(4) (5)` fail, and I would like to understand why.

## Workaround?!

I've found a workaround, by specializing `my_fwd` for `Ret == void`:

```
// with this specialization i can avoid the error
template<class ORet, class... OArgs,
         class... Args>
struct my_fwd<
  my_func<ORet(OArgs...)>,
  my_func<void(Args...)>
  >
{
  my_func< ORet() > func;
};
```

## Question

What's the difference between the compiler trying to instantiate inside

`my_fwd< my_func<void(int)>, my_func<void(char)> >`:

-> `my_func<void(void)> func`

and

the *manual* version in main(): `my_func<void(void)> my4`?

Was the `void` specialization the *correct* approach for a fix?  Alternatives?  I'm obviously not excited about specializations and code duplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between instatiating with `void` as a template parameter and manually writing `void (void)` is that the latter does *not* produce a function taking a `void` parameter. Listing `(void)` as a function's parameters is a syntactic construct whose meaning is the same as `()`. It's a legacy from C, where `()` means "parameters are unspecified" and `(void)` means "no parameters." C++ removed the unspecified case, and `()` means "no parameters" there.

However, template instantiation happens long after syntactic processing, so actually trying to instantiate a function's parameters `(T)` with `T = void` results in an error. Just as it would be an error to try to declare a function taking `(std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<void*>())>::type)` (i.e. `void` actually spelled out as a type).

I am afraid the only way you can solve this is indeed by specialising for `void`.