# std::conditional - Invalid parameter type ‘void’ even when testing for 'void'

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, conditional-types, class-template

The following compiles on Visual Studio:

```
template<typename ArgType, typename ReturnType>
struct Test
{
    using FunctionPointerType = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_same_v<ArgType, void>
        , ReturnType(*)()
        , ReturnType(*)(ArgType)
    >;
    FunctionPointerType Func;
};

int main()
{
    Test<void, char> tt;
}
```

But does not compile on Linux g++.  The error I get is

```
error : invalid parameter type ‘void’
```

I know I cannot use void in templates, which is why I have used `std::conditional_t` and `std::is_same_v`.

I cannot see what is incorrect, can someone please tell me?

Comment: "I know I cannot use void in templates"  Says who?

Comment: Anyway, in your specific case using a partial specialization would be much simpler.

Comment: A specialization may also be necessary, since when instantiating `std::conditional_t<B, T, F>`, both the type `T` for if `B` is `true` and the type `F` for if `B` is `false` must be valid. Since the problem is that `char(*)(void)` is invalid and you want `char*()`, `conditional_t` isn't the appropriate tool here.

Comment: @BenVoigt It looks like the problem comes up in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249882/invalid-void-parameter-when-combining-template-parameters-to-form-a-function-sig), where the function signature you'd get by declaring `char foo(void);` isn't the same as what you'd get by performing the substitution with `ArgType = void`

Comment: Simplified with working but strange text case - live - https://godbolt.org/z/TT1qfdW85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `std::conditional_t<B, T, F>` both the `true` and `false` specialization should have valid types `T` as well as `F`. In your case, since the `F` deduce to an invalid `char(*)(void)` type, `std::conditional` can not be used here.

I would suggest a helper traits `function_ptr_t` as alternative

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename RetType, typename... Args> struct function_ptr final {
    using type = RetType(*)(Args...);
};

template <typename RetType> struct function_ptr<RetType, void> final {
    using type = RetType(*)();
};
// alias helper
template<typename RetType, typename... Args>
using function_ptr_t = typename function_ptr<RetType, Args...>::type;


template<typename RetType, typename... Args>
struct Test
{
     function_ptr_t<RetType, Args...> Func;
};
```

**[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b4nxd5YhE)**

---

Note that, I have swapped the template arguments in the class template `Test`, and made the second template argument be a variadic, so that the `Test<char>` will result in a member function pointer of type `char(*)()`.

That means the following will work:

```
Test<char> tt1;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<char(*)(), decltype(tt1.Func)>, " are not same!");

Test<char, void> tt2;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<char(*)(), decltype(tt2.Func)>, " are not same!");

Test<void, double> tt3;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<void(*)(double), decltype(tt3.Func)>, " are not same!");
```

If that is not, you wanted, substitute the variadic template arguments to be a normal one.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question (Why doesn't my code work), but this works:

```
template<typename ArgType, typename ReturnType>
struct Test
{
  using FunctionPointerType = ReturnType(*)(ArgType);
  FunctionPointerType Func;
};

template<typename ReturnType>
struct Test<void, ReturnType>
{
  using FunctionPointerType = ReturnType(*)();
  FunctionPointerType Func;
};
```

Comment: I think that the problem is that `std::conditional` needs both of the result types to be valid.

Comment: @JeJo: This is simple enough to be a trait.

Comment: @JeJo, I ended up using your type traits example code; this solves my problem.  Please post your comment and code as an answer, and I will accept it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename ArgType, typename ReturnType>
struct Test
{
  using FunctionPointerType = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<ArgType, void>, ReturnType(*)(), ReturnType(*)(ArgType)>;
  FunctionPointerType Func;
};
```

`conditional_t` takes 3 arguments.  A `bool` and 2 types.

The right type, when `ArgType` is `void`, is `ReturnType(*)(void)` -- not a legal type.

The error happens immediately.

MSVC has a bad habit of treating templates like macros.

Something like this:

```
template<class...Args>
struct Apply {
  template<template<class...>class Z>
  using To = Z<Args...>;
};

template<class R, class...Args>
using FunctionPtr = R(*)(Args...);

template<typename ArgType, typename ReturnType>
struct Test
{
  using FunctionPointerType =
    std::conditional_t<
      std::is_same_v<ArgType, void>,
      Apply<ReturnType>,
      Apply<ReturnType, ArgType>
    >::template To<FunctionPtr>;
  FunctionPointerType Func;
};
```

builds 2 pack appliers, then applies one to `FunctionPtr` depending on which one is picked.

Here, I avoid forming `X(void)` types until after the condition branch has occurred.