# Template parameter type `void` vs explicit use of `void`

Tags: c++

In the following code why does the explicit expansion of template function `foo` fail to compile, yet the expansion of `bar` compiles successfully ?  Live link - https://godbolt.org/z/o8Ea49KEb

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 foo(T2) { T2(42); return T1{}; };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 bar(void) { T2(42); return T1{}; };

int main()
{
    foo<int, void>();    // fails

    bar<int, void>();    // works
}
```

Note that the template parameter `T2` is used in the body of both functions and the only difference is that the function parameter to `bar` has been manually substituted.

This question was inspired after reading [std::conditional - Invalid parameter type ‘void’ even when testing for 'void'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72381198/stdconditional-invalid-parameter-type-void-even-when-testing-for-void) and trying to simplify the issue.

Comment: `T1 bar(void)` that's an archaic form for `T1 bar()` and it doesn't really accepts any arguments. `T1 foo(T2)` requires to accept an argument - but there is no such thing as accepting a `void` for an argument.

Comment: Since there is no **function** partial template specialization (*sad panda*), you could `template <typename T1> T1 foo() { return T1{}; };` and `foo<int>();`, and omit the `void` entirely.  As a workaround.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The rule saying a parameter list `(void)` is the same as the empty parameter list `()` is found in C++ Standard [[dcl.fct]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct#4):

> A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type `void` is equivalent to an empty parameter list. Except for this special case, a parameter shall not have type *cv* `void`.

The important piece for this question is "non-dependent type". The template parameter `T` is type-dependent, so it doesn't trigger the rule.

I presume the Standard has this rule because it would also be quite confusing (I'd say worse) if a template function which normally takes one parameter could suddenly become a zero-parameter function if an instantiation happens to make that parameter type `void`. With this rule, we know when a template is declared with a parameter, it really has one parameter.

Comment: I'd say the only reason why `int foo(void)` is valid at all is to be compatible with some old C-style code.

Comment: @ALX23z `int foo(void);` is not an old C style - it's recommended in modern C, since `int foo();` is not a prototype and allows for any number of parameters and/or arguments without consistency checks. But yes, that's the reason it's allowed in C++.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T) {}

void bar(void) {}
```

You are assuming `foo<void>` and `bar(void)` are equivalent, but they are not. `foo<T>` always requires an argument. So `foo<void>` is equivalent to a function `baz(void x)`. This does not compile, as you cannot have a value of type void. That is the same error message you got.

In the function signature `void bar(void)` the void in brackets signifies something different: a function without arguments. This is a remnant of C and not recommended.

The functions `bar<void>(T)`  and `baz(void x)` cannot exists, because they both require a value of type `void`, which cannot exist.

The solution with template functions is to provide overloads or specialisations for cases where a template instantiation would be illegal.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T) {} // one argument

void foo() {}  // no arguments -> different signatures -> overload

template<typename T> 
void bar() {}  // no arguments

template<>
void bar<void> {} // still no arguments -> same signature -> specialisation
```